# Downvoting after Upvoting Requires You to Have Some Reputation?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, down-votes, up-votes

Downvoting requires you to have a certain amount of rep which is completely reasonable but downvoting after you mistakenly upvoted a question or an answer should not require you to have some rep. I don't see any point. If you upvote an answer or a question, you should be able to downvote it too, maybe not after ages but within a reasonable period of time. Maybe after you upvoted, the question/answer was edited and sounded wrong to you. So, you decided to change your vote. It should be a ok.

To Err is Programmers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't downvote to reverse an upvote, you simply click on the upvote arrow again.

Answer (score 3):

Down-voting always requires you to have a minimum of 100 rep...
But I think you can 'undo' an up-vote (by clicking on the up-vote arrow again in stead of clicking on the down-vote arrow) with less rep.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing people to undo a vote by clicking the opposite vote seems like an OK idea.  It does not have to replace the current behavior.   Both might make StackExchange a tiny bit more users friendly.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but an idea would be allow the user to choose (in preferences) what happens when downvoting an alread-upvoted post.