# Changing a downvote to an upvote

Tags: discussion, locked-votes, change-vote

I down voted a question because it was a poor answer. After this the answer was edited. I click the down vote to remove my down vote, then I go to click upvote to give it an upvote. A small notification pop's up telling me that it's too old to be changed unless it's edited.

Why is this done? I then have to go find an arbitrary thing to edit just to give it an upvote.

Comment: I know this exact issue has been discussed before, but the best I can see now is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8390/downvoting-should-cancel-an-upvote-before-attempting-to-apply-the-downvote (and the question linked from it) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40683/upvoting-a-downvoted-answer-will-do-2-upvote.

Comment: *I down voted a **question** because it was a poor **answer**?* what the what?

Comment: @julio.alegria: Don't ask me what I was thinking when I wrote this two years ago. It could very well be I meant to say “down voted an *post* because it was a poor answer.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just not how it works, and I've been bitten by it too.

The current way to turn a downvote into an upvote is to just upvote, without "canceling" the down vote.

Comment: I really hate non-intuitive interfaces.  There has got to be a better way to address voter fraud than that stupid vote timer.

Comment: Agreed, it's just not a big enough problem right now for me to worry about.

Comment: I'll do that from now on, but that vote timer is a PITA.